# Unable to insert more than 1 node in BST in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
class Node<K> {

      public K key;
      public int height;

      public Node<K> left, right, parent;

      public Node(K x, Node<K> l, Node<K> r, Node<K> p) {

        key = x;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        parent = p;
        height = 1;

      }
    }

    public class AVLFrom<K extends Comparable<K>> {

      public Node<K> root;
      // it should be private for software engineering and abstraction purposes
      // but I want to check your tree shapes in my tester, so forgive me

      public AVLFrom() {
        root = null;

      }

      public void insert(K k) {

        root = BSTinsert(k, root, null);


      }

      private Node<K> BSTinsert(K k, Node<K> v, Node<K> parent) {
          if (v == null) {

              return new Node<K>(k, null, null, parent);  
          }
          else {
              int m = k.compareTo(v.key);
              //if k > v, then insert in right subtree
              if (m > 0) {


                 v.right = BSTinsert(k, v.right, v);

              }
              //if k <= v, insert in left subtree
              else {
                  v.left = BSTinsert(k, v.left, v );

              }

            }

          return v;

         }
```

I am creating an AVL tree but since I am very unfamiliar with Java, I just wanted to create a normal BST to try to get the hang of java and then modify it from there to make it into an AVL tree. Unfortunately I am unable to add multiple nodes.

For example if I write the code below:

```
AVLFrom<Integer> s = new AVLFrom<Integer>();

        s.insert(5);
        s.insert(10);
```

The code runs without any errors.

Then if I write in the following code in the **insert** method:

```
System.out.println(root.key);
System.out.println(root.right.key);
```

Eclipse prints the value 5 but then I get a NullPointerException at the "root.right.key" part.

But if I add the following code in the **BSTinsert** method:

```
System.out.println(v.key);
System.out.println(v.right.key);
```

Eclipse prints 5 and 10.

I have no idea why this is happening because if v and v.right are printing 5 and 10 properly, when I return v and assign it to the variable "root", it shouldn't be getting a NullPointerException error when trying to print root.right. I would appreciate any help.

It seems to me that all nodes that get "connected" to the root node being passed in BSTinsert don't say connected/attached when v is returned in the BSTinsert method. I have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE comes during the first `insert` where `root.right` is null. The following modification will fix the issue.

```
System.out.println(root.right != null ? root.right.key : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh god, I just think I realized the error. When I inserted the 5, in the insert function, I printed root AND root.right before even inserting the second element and that is why I kept getting the NullPointerException! –